# Why is Terminal complaining "-bash: export: `PATH;': not a valid identifier"

Tags: bash

When I start terminal I get the error

> -bash: export: `PATH;': not a valid identifier

Why?

I've looked in the two files which [I think](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/1495/142445) bash uses at startup, and I cannot see an issue:

**/etc/profile**

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)  

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then  
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`  
fi  

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then  
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc  
fi
```

**~/.bash_profile**

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/autoconf/bin"  
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/automake/bin"  
export VISUAL=vscodeeval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)
```

(N.B. The file `/usr/libexec/path_helper` is binary, and `/etc/bashrc` does not contain the text 'PATH'.)

Where is the error coming from? I cannot see `PATH;` with the trailing semicolon in either startup profile.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the last line of your bash_profile?

Comment: I'm not, I think that's the out-of-the-box profile. At least none of it looks familiar to me.

Comment: But removing that line fixes things! Thanks. I wonder what added it.

Comment: I've added this as a VS Code issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20196) just-in-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to turn fd0's comment into an answer, the offending line in my ~/.bash_profile file is the last one

```
export VISUAL=vscodeeval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)
```

Removing that line fixes the problem and appears to have no bad effects. Sadly I cannot remember nor work out why it was there

Answer (score 3):

Look at the output of `path_helper -s`:

```
$ /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="..."; export PATH;
```

(The actual value assigned to `PATH` isn't important; I've elided it here.)

The output is intended to be executed with `eval`, as it is in `/etc/profile`. The purpose is to provide an initial value for the `PATH` variable, then set the export attribute on the name.

In your `.bash_profile`, you are unnecessarily executing it *again*, but also incorrectly letting the output be used as additional arguments to an `export` command. The line

```
export VISUAL=vscodeeval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)
```

is treated as

```
export VISUAL=vscodeeval PATH="..."; export PATH;
```

except the semicolons are treated as literal characters, not command terminators. Thus, it tries to do the following:

1. Set `VISUAL` to `vscodeval` and set the export attribute on `VISUAL`. That's OK.
2. Set `PATH` to an initial value (ending with a semicolon, which would not be what you want, but syntactically not an issue) and set its export attribute.
3. Set the export attribute on a variable named `export`. Unnecessary, but not an error.
4. Set the export attribute on a variable named `PATH;`. That is your error, since a variable name cannot contain a `;`.

The fix is to just remove the `$(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)` from your `.bash_profile`; it only needs to be executed once from `/etc/profile`.